# Implementing two HashMaps

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a combination of two HashMaps.Below is my code,but i am not able to produce what i really wanted.
The result of my code is :

```
{{userId1=clientID1}=timestamp1}
{{userId1=clientID1, userId2=clientID2}=timestamp2, {userId1=clientID1, userId2=clientID2}=timestamp1}
```

Actually i need :

```
{{userId1=clientID1}=timestamp1},{userId2=clientID2}=timestamp2},{userId3=clientID3}=timestamp3}..}
```

that is ,one to one mapping.Can we really implement this requirement?If no can anybody suggest a way for this type of mapping.I will be really thankful...

```
public static void main (String args[]) 
{
HashMap map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
HashMap<HashMap,String>  multi = new HashMap();
map.put("userId1", "clientID1");
multi.put(map, "timestamp1");

System.out.println(multi);   //gives me correct requirement

map.put("userId2", "clientID2");
multi.put(map, "timestamp2");

System.out.println(multi);   //since the table is filled again a combination of values results(each time it keeps on increasing) which is not really required as per my requirement .Hope my problem is clear.please do help me ..
}
```

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense at least to me.  Can you elaborate in non-code terms what you're trying to achieve, including the details?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is what classes have been invented for.

Comment: In general, using mutable object as keys for Maps is a VERY BAD practice

Comment: The API for AbstractMap states that its hashCode (and thus HashMap's hashCode) is defined as the sum of the hashCodes of each entry in its entrySet, and so I think that the most egregious crime committed here is using an object whose hashCode value changes as a map's key.

Answer (score 2):

What are the reasons why you can't simply use two separate maps, one being userId -> clientId and the other one being userId -> timestamp? What is the reason for using Map as a Map's key at the first place?

Remember that Map is mutable in Java and using a mutable object as a key for a Map is generally a VERY BAD practice.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not two HashMap but only one. The value of the map should be composed of client_id and timestamp.

See this code:

```
public class Compose {
  int clientId;
  Date timestamp;
}
```

And the map will be HashMap where the key is user_id and the value is Compose.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're incrementing the number of elements in your first `HashMap` as you go along. Think about what the `map` HashMap contains during the first and the second `add` operations to `multi`.

To fix this you will need to create a new HashMap each time you add something to `multi`

```
HashMap<HashMap,String>  multi = new HashMap();
HashMap<String,String> key = new HashMap<String,String>();
key.add("userID","clientID");
multi.add(key,"timestamp");

HashMap<String,String> key = new HashMap<String,String>();
key.add("userID2","clientID2");
multi.add(key,"timestamp");
```

You can see that will become somewhat unwieldy and isn't the most memory efficient. What I would do instead is perhaps create a combined string key like `userID:clientID` and use that in multi instead

```
HashMap<HashMap,String>  multi = new HashMap();
multi.add("userID:clientID","timestamp");
```

I don't know if this is possible for your application though.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom Object instead, something like this:

```
public class Mapping{

    private final String userId;
    private final String clientId;

    public Mapping(final String userId, final String clientId){
        this.userId = userId;
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public String getUserId(){
        return userId;
    }

    public String getClientId(){
        return clientId;
    }

    // implement hashcode and equals using userId and clientId,
    // or it won't work !!!

}
```

Now use this object as the key in your HashMap (a timestamp should probably be a `long` / `Long`):

```
Map<Mapping,Long> clientMappings = new HashMap<Mapping,Long>();

// register a client mapping
clientMappings.put(new Mapping(userId, clientId), System.currentTimeMillis());

// get a client mapping timestamp, will be null if no such mapping exists
Long timeStamp = clientMappings.get(new Mapping(userId, clientId));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the line

```
map.put("userId2", "clientID2");
```

You are adding the values to the old Hashmap, but you need to create a secound HashMap.

The following should do the trick.

```
public static void main (String args[]) 
{
HashMap map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
HashMap<HashMap,String>  multi = new HashMap();
map.put("userId1", "clientID1");
multi.put(map, "timestamp1");

System.out.println(multi);   //gives me correct requirement

map = new HashMap();
map.put("userId2", "clientID2");
multi.put(map, "timestamp2");

System.out.println(multi);   //since the table is filled again a combination of values results(each time it keeps on increasing) which is not really required as per my requirement .Hope my problem is clear.please do help me ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why you want to do what you are describing, but if you elaborate I am quite sure that there is a better design than what you are currently trying to use.

However, if you want to carry on down the same path then your problem seems to be that you are updating "map" over and over again and this reference is not changing. You would need to create a new HashMap object for your key every time else when you change the elements on map, this change will filter through to multi.

Have you tried something like this:

```
Map<Map, String> multi = new HashMap<Map, String>();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("userId1", "clientID1");
multi.put(map, "timestamp1");

map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put("userId2", "clientID2");
multi.put(map, "timestamp2");
```

Notice the second instantiation of map of above.

Comment: Just as a further comment on best practices, you may want to rather code to Map interface instead of to the concrete HashMap class as I have done above. In other words "Map<Map, String> multi =..." instead of "HashMap<HashMap, String> multi = ". This has several advantages, for example if you later decide to change the Map implementation you are using, then this will make the change easy. Also your use of generics seems a bit inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a class, containing clientId, userId and timestamp fields:

```
class ClientDetails {
   String clientId;
   String userId;
   Date timestamp;
}
```

and then create a map using clientId as a key and ClientDetails as a value.

However, if you need to use this class as a key - you have to at least override the equals(Object obj) method. Below is a sample:

```
public class Main {

    public class Client {

        public String clientId;
        public String userId;

        public Client(String p_clientId, String p_userID) {

            this.clientId = p_clientId;
            this.userId = p_userID;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {

            boolean result = false;
            if (obj != null && obj instanceof Client) {
                Client client = (Client) obj;
                if (client.clientId.equals(clientId)
                        && client.userId.equals(userId)) {

                    result = true;
                } else {
                    result = false;
                }
            } else {
                result = super.equals(obj);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main main = new Main();
        Map<Client, Date> hashMap = new HashMap<Client, Date>();
        hashMap.put(main.new Client("clientId1", "userId1"), new Date());
    }

}
```

I've ommitted some of null checks for the sake of clarity.